# SET diffrenet DEFAULT pages for 2 diffrenet directories with same project path in iis 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, server, iis-8

**I created a virtual directory with name test with a path D:\Proj\myapp and default document as login.aspx , now when i create another virtual directory with name test2 with SAME path D:\Proj\myapp but with different default document as la_login.aspx then the default document when i browse is chosen from the virtual directory which was created first....in IIS 5 and IIS 6 i am able to get the different default pages but on IIS 8 it is redirected to the same default document.**

Answer (score 0):

Go to - %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config 
Open applicationhost.config

Update location tag for virtual directory for default document as below.

```
<location path="www.yoursite.com" overrideMode="Allow">
   <system.webServer>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" showFlags="None" />
     <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script" />
     <defaultDocument enabled="true">
       <files>
         <clear />
         <add value="newPage.aspx" />
       </files>
     </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Comment: thankyou for your response ,i am not able to find out the applicationhost.config in the system .

Comment: What this gives you? windows key + R > then paste  %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config hit enter.

Comment: Are you checking this on web server?

Comment: yes actually i had checked it on iis 6 mistakenly so i was not able to access the applicationhost.config